# Bootstrap Alert Div is not display on second ajax request when cancel on first Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a dismissible alert in my html file which is hidden in starting. code below.

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="msgdiv" style="margin-bottom:5px;display: none;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <span id="emsg"></span>
</div>
```

Now I send an Ajax request to submit the form and based on response, First I show this div which was hidden till now and then add success or error class to this div.

```
console.log($("#msgdiv"));
$("#msgdiv").show();
if (result.is_success) {
    $("#msgdiv").removeClass("alert-warning");
    $("#msgdiv").addClass("alert-success");

} else {
    $("#msgdiv").removeClass("alert-success");
    $("#msgdiv").addClass("alert-warning");
}
$("#emsg").html(result.message);
```

Now when response is returned first time, this div is displayed. I cancel the div by click on cross button.
I submit the form with new values using Ajax second time without refreshing the page and this div is not displayed.  Same result was returned in both cases.
I printed the div element in both scenario in JS code and below is the output.

**First Time:**

```
[div#msgdiv.alert.alert-dismissible, context: document, selector: "#msgdiv"]
```

**Second Time:**

```
n.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#msgdiv"}
```

more details in image below.

[image]

Why is this happening? why there is difference in console log? What is its meaning from HTML and JS perspective.

Comment: Hi. The first JS code you have show as example belongs to a function or something that is always called after your new Ajax response? We can build a fiddle or runnable code to reproduce ur case better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an alert is closed, it is removed from the DOM.

If you want to an alert to reappear later, remove data-dismiss="alert" in the close button as follows:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="msgdiv" style="margin-bottom:5px;display: none;">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <span id="emsg"></span>
</div>
```

Then, bind the close button to simply hide the alert when it's pressed:

```
$('.alert .close').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```